# Max Retention of Old Releases

Tags: update-manager

I currently had a problem where my INODES hit 100%.  This was a real pain to get resolved because everything I tried to do failed because it couldn't create a tmp file.

In the end, I found that when Update Manager upgrades the Linux Kernel, it leaves a the old /usr/src/linux header directories out there.  Each of these has over 1K files in them.  I had headers from 3.2.0.12 up to 49.  Basically, this combined with PHP Doc had used up all my INODES.

Is there a way to have the update manager keep say only the last 4 or 5 versions and automatically delete anything older than that?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: You should have room for several million inodes.  A few k here and there aren't going to use them all up.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that isn't built in to UpdateManager anywhere.

You may find [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-to-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu) to be related, although not identical.

Comment: Thanks...I installed synaptic and removed all but the last 5 versions.  It would be nice if the package manager did that on it's own.

Comment: It would, but that would be a feature request bug on launchpad.  Reasons that may not be the default behavior - "I installed a realtime kernel for audio editing, the generic kernel for a stable boot, and some kernel stuffs.  Now when I upgrade my kernel it waxed my old ones and I can't boot.  HALP!!!"

Comment: If it solved your problem don't forget to vote or accept.